# Checking if a number is even and evenly divisible by 3 or 7

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing a program for a edhesive Ap programming course. The program asks the user to input three integers that must adhere to certain conditions.

The first number must be the number 3.
The second number can either be the number 1 or be between 33 and 100, inclusive.
The third number must be a positive number that is either evenly divisible by 3 or evenly divisible by 7

I'm getting zero errors when testing personally, however, when inputting the code in edhesives coderunner its not passing.

I wanted to check and see if I'm using my if statement conditions correctly specifically the third condition or phase 3.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.lang.Math; 

class Main2{
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      String name;
      int phase1;
      int phase2;
      int phase3;
      int flag = 1;
      int flag2 = 0;


      System.out.println("Welcome. What is your name?");
        name = scan.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Hello "+name+". Try your best to crack the code!");

      while(flag == 1){
        System.out.println("PHASE 1");

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        phase1 = scan.nextInt();

        if(phase1 == 3){
          System.out.println("Correct!");
          flag2++;}
        else{
           System.out.println("Sorry, that was incorrect!\nBetter luck next time");
          break;
        }


        System.out.println("PHASE 2");

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        phase2 = scan.nextInt();

        if(phase2 == 1 || (phase2 > 33 && phase2 <100)){
           System.out.println("Correct!");
           flag2++;}
        else{
           System.out.println("Sorry, that was incorrect!\nBetter luck next time!");
          break;
        }

        System.out.println("PHASE 3");

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        phase3 = scan.nextInt();

        if(phase3 % 2 == 0 && (phase3 % 3 == 0 || phase3 % 7 == 0)){
           System.out.println("Correct!");
           flag2++;}
          else{
           System.out.println("Sorry, that was incorrect!\nBetter luck next time!");
          break;
        }

         if(flag2==3)
           flag=2;
         System.out.println("You have cracked the code!");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code tested by a program? If so, are you sure that you are using the correct output pattern specified by the problem? Problems like usually have output standards to correct it

Comment: Why do you check for phase3 % 2 == 0?

Comment: My guess is, that "inclusive" means  (phase2 >= 33 && phase2 <=100)

Comment: You should design your test cases *carefully* and make sure your code passes all of your own tests before you submit it. The second number must be between 33 and 100 inclusive; therefore *test* with numbers 32, 33, 34, 99, 100, 101. It should pass all except 32 and 101. Your code doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the question title you say "number is even", but in the question you say the number should be positive. Those are very different things.

In phase 2, your condition is not inclusive.

In phase 3, I don't see you confirming if the number is positive, assuming that was what you want. "phase3 % 2 == 0" doesn't check for positiveness, it checks if the number can be divided by 2 (and thus is even).

Answer (score 0):

1. Evenly divisible means that you have no remainder. in your 3rd if condition no necessity of checking if(phase3 % 2 == 0) because that's not required.
2. between 33 and 100 inclusive means you should put condition >= and <= rather than > and <